# attribute transfer from one Element to others

Tags: xml, xslt

Need a little decision-pattern help. Can't assemly code for simple goal.

What i need.

--1 in the base XML file i've got a parent element with unique ID (non-numeric, like 'd124914-a402-ab72-949a") attribute

--2 and then i've got over 10 child-elements

--3  (what to do)

------> to get (by variable?) this attribute value

------> insert this ID-unique attribute to the others over10 elements in addition to theirs already existing attributes

Thanx!

Comment: can you please share code sample which will help to understand better and answer your desire question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <parent id="100">
        <child id="1">alpha</child>
        <child id="2">bravo</child>
        <child id="3">charlie</child>
    </parent>
    <parent id="200">
        <child id="4">red</child>
        <child id="5">green</child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child">
    <child parent-id="{../@id}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </child>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <parent id="100">
    <child parent-id="100" id="1">alpha</child>
    <child parent-id="100" id="2">bravo</child>
    <child parent-id="100" id="3">charlie</child>
  </parent>
  <parent id="200">
    <child parent-id="200" id="4">red</child>
    <child parent-id="200" id="5">green</child>
  </parent>
</root>
```

---

To better understand this, read about [attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#attribute-value-templates).

Comment: thank you! Yes, now it works on 90%. New attribute is adding to child-element. But i can't get "sought-for" value. Suspect that's cos of my wrong path-typing in this expression: (parent-id="{../@id}")
While i have empty quotes in a place of value. What i typed? hierarchical location of the Parent {Parent/@ParentID} (is it wrong?) Also tried to include Parent's-parent name {File/Parent/@ParentID}

Comment: Please edit your question and add a minimal example showing your XML, XSLT and the expected result - see: [mcve].